# Event binding in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is there any difference between the following:  (Is there any reason to avoid example One?)

One:

```
$("#stuff").on("resize", function() { doThis(); });
$("#stuff").on("resize", function() { doThat(); });
```

Two:

```
$("#stuff").on("resize", function() { 
  doThis(); 
  doThat();
});
```

Comment: With example one, you can do: `$("#stuff").on("resize", doThis).on("resize", doThat);`

Comment: Try using Conversation to decouple it a bit:   https://github.com/rhyneandrew/Conversation.JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straightforwardly, there's no real difference.

In real-world code,

- You may need to attach the two handlers in different places in your code, in which case you have to use version One (or similar).
- You may want the ability to selectively detach handlers, in which case, the event can be namespaced as follows:

Attach handlers:

```
$("#stuff").on("resize.A", function() { doThis(); });
...
$("#stuff").on("resize.B", function() { doThat(); });
```

Detach one handler:

```
$("#stuff").off("resize.A");
```

The handler for `resize.B` remains attached (ie. `doThis()` will not be called but `doThat()` will be called) .

Comment: Depending on what your functions are doing, I agree with @Beetroot-Beetroot. Binding them separately while naming allows you to remove one or the other easily.

Answer (score 2):

In your second example, if `doThis()` throws an exception then `doThat()` won't run. Not the case with the first example.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is that two distinct *event handler functions* are stored and executed wheres the second snippet is satisfied with one.

Do the math, second snippet is more elegant. I won't start talking about performance, but if we would bind like "hundreds" of methods that way, it becomes obvious that you don't want to bind multiple handlers.

Answer (score 0):

The second will be a little more performant.

In the first example, you have the overhead of two function calls when the resize event fires (in addition to the calls to doThis and doThat). In the second example, you only have one event handler being called.

Comment: Nope - but it's a fairly common term in the computer science world. It's nice to have a succinct way to say that something performs well.

Comment: It isn't common round here.

Comment: Okay. I'm not entirely sure what you'd like me to do with that.

Comment: Kevin, keep on using it. I'm more flexible than I like to make out sometimes.